# How to let ThingsBoard connect to an independent MQTT broker?

Tags: thingsboard

It seems that ThingsBoard implements its own MQTT broker and connector with Netty. We are trying to use an independent MQTT broker, how do we make ThingsBoard connect to that broker with minimum effort?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ThingsBoard IoT Gateway project. It allows to connect to external MQTT broker and acts as an API bridge between your broker and ThingsBoard. For example, you can subscribe to custom topics and extract telemetry values or attribute updates from it. Similar with ThingsBoard RPC calls. Browse the following docs for an example of integration with AWS IoT:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/integration-with-aws-iot/

Comment: I am aware of ThingBoard IoT Gateway project, but I am confused about it. By its name "gateway", I always think it is a software gateway like those hardware IoT gateway, so it is mostly running on edge side like in factory. But by the document, to me it looks like it is running on server side in the middle of MQTT broker and ThingsBoard. Confuse me.

Comment: You can install it both on the device and on the server. Sorry for possible confusion.

Comment: Thanks. I am also interested in why ThingsBoard needs ThingsBoard IoT Gateway to connect to other MQTT broker instead of having the capability by itself? Any interesting design thoughts behind it?